# How to convert from double to signed short?

Tags: c

What's the easiest way to convert a variable from `double` to `signed short`?

I'm a total beginner to DSP. In other C-language environments I did this task in the following manner:

```
double myDouble = - 3.14;

myDouble = floor(myDouble);
signed short = (signed short) myDouble;
```

Surprisingly that doesn't work for negative numbers in VisualDSP++, but still it compiles.

I'm using ADSP-BF548 EZ-KIT LITE (blackfin) and programming environment VisualDSP++ 5.0.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can't you, as a workaround, check if the value is `<0` and then negate it, convert to a signed short and negate the result?

Comment: What you have there won't compile - you didn't give your `signed short` a name.  Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: Of course I should have asked what is "doesn't work" first. Error? Random value for a result?

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? In C language the above must work perfectly well for all numbers in range, once the name error is fixed.

Comment: Is this audio related? Are you trying to convert floating point audio samples to PCM 16-bit samples? (I ask because you mentioned you're dealing with DSPs.)

Comment: In addition to telling us how it "doesn't work", please explain how you want the conversion to behave. Rounding? Truncating toward 0? Truncating toward -infinity? What `signed short` value do you want `-3.14` to convert to?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to round towards zero, this would be be perfectly enough

```
double myDouble = - 3.14;
short s = myDouble;
```

If you want to round towards negative infinity, then just add `floor`

```
double myDouble = - 3.14;
short s = floor(myDouble);
```

In either case there's no need for an explicit cast from `double` to `short`, but it might be a good idea to keep it just to keep compilers from issuing warnings.

And, of course, it is your responsibility to make sure that the original value is in range of `short`.

If this somehow "doesn't work" (whatever that means) when it should, then the compiler you use must be broken.

Comment: @Mr Lister: The OP didn't not provide enough details to determine what he meant by that vague "didn't work" statement.